# Can I make haskell GADT data constructor infix in derived Show?

Tags: haskell, gadt, deriving, infix-operator

Consider two `data` declarations:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data X = Int `Y` Int deriving Show

data Z where
        W :: Int -> Int -> Z  deriving Show

main = do
         print (1 `Y` 2)
         print (3 `W` 4)
```

Running the above program produces:

```
1 `Y` 2
W 3 4
```

so the derived `show` knows that `Y` is infix and prints it accordingly. The `::` syntax doesn't seem to allow infixness.

Is there any way to make the compiler derive show for `W` as infix, (other than explicitly providing a `show` instance for `Z`)?
The desired output is

```
1 `Y` 2
3 `W` 4
```

Comment: I never knew you could tell the `Show` deriver to print a non-symbolic constructor infix.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not currently. GADT constructors are only flagged as infix [under a specific set of conditions](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/typecheck/TcTyClsDecls.hs#L1752):

> ```
> Note [Infix GADT constructors]
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> We do not currently have syntax to declare an infix constructor in GADT syntax,
> but it makes a (small) difference to the Show instance.  So as a slightly
> ad-hoc solution, we regard a GADT data constructor as infix if
>   a) it is an operator symbol
>   b) it has two arguments
>   c) there is a fixity declaration for it
> For example:
>    infix 6 (:--:)
>    data T a where
>      (:--:) :: t1 -> t2 -> T Int
> ```

So for a non-symbolic constructor like `W`, it looks like you're out of luck, but if you're willing to make it symbolic, you can just add a fixity declaration.

(hat tip to [this template haskell bug thread](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11345#comment:8))

Comment: Perhaps a) should be dropped? If the user specified a fixity, maybe the binary constructor is expected to be used infix, I'd guess.